# Access files in system tmp directory, when using PrivateTmp

Tags: systemd, systempath

I am using `php-fpm` with PrivateTmp enabled. I have to read a file from PHP, which is copied by a remote deployment agent to the `/tmp` directory. Since PrivateTmp is enabled, I am unable to directly access `/tmp` directory.

Is it possible to read a file from the system `/tmp` folder when PrivateTmp is enabled? I tried creating a symbolic link to `/tmp` at `/var/temp` and accessing the file through `/var/temp`, but it did not work. `/var/tmp` is currently bind mounted from `/tmp`, and I also tried accessing the file through `/var/tmp` without any success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=)  please:

> **`PrivateTmp=`**
>   Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` directories inside it that is not shared by processes outside of the namespace. This is useful to secure access to temporary files of the process, but **makes sharing between processes via `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` impossible.**

So no you can't read from the systemwide `/tmp/` directory.

But there is a work-around in that same section of the manual:

> ... It is possible to run two or more units within the same private /tmp and /var/tmp namespace by using the `JoinsNamespaceOf=` directive, see [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#JoinsNamespaceOf=) for details.

So if your remote deployment agent is also running from a systemd unit you can join them together in a single PrivateTmp shared between them that is still separate from the rest of the system.

If you can't do that: don't store the file in the system `/tmp/` and simply have it placed/moved another location...

Comment: There should be a workaround with nsenter or something, but we would need to know how systemd implements their wizardry.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nsenter` to run a command inside the network namespace.

So for example, if you wanted to see the files inside /tmp for the apache2 service you could do something like this:

```sh
pid=$(systemctl show --property=MainPID --value apache2.service)
nsenter -t $pid -m ls /tmp
```

This will run `ls /tmp` inside the mount namespace that the apache2 process is running in.

Also, the private tmp directory currently is located at a path like `/tmp/systemd-private-*-apache2.service-*` where the `*` are some kind of id. Although you probably shouldn't rely on a specific format or location for that.